# Intellij package does not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

IntelliJ 2022.3.2 Ultimate
MacOS (latest)

Stumped ...

Project A builds fine, installs jar file in local repo, ~/.m2/repository/...
Project B has a dependency on Project A. Looks like it's there in Maven -> Dependencies.
Project B does not compile, "package ? does not exist".
I manually copy the jar to ./lib and add it in the module dependencies for Project B. Again, Maven -> dependencies lists the jar file.
Inside the jar file in BOOT-INF/classes/... the class files are there.

IntelliJ does not recognize the jar file, no matter what I do. Basic stuff here. I've tried all tricks except the one that fixes the problem. I've changed the java version to 11 from 17. Used maven compiler plugin with source and target set to 11. Disabled additional IntelliJ plugins I had installed. Nothing in idea.log that stands out. Project B simply can't find the jar for Project A.

Project A and Project B are spring boot projects. I've done local dependencies before and everything has worked fine, except in this case.

TIA,
Eric

Project A pom.xml:

```
...
<name>proj-a</name>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>proj-a</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
...
```

Project B pom.xml:

```
...
<name>proj-b</name>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>proj-b</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>proj-a</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
...
```

Comment: I noticed IntelliJ was updated late January, 2023. Done automatically through JetBrains Toolbox. Full paid subscription.

Comment: If you have already added the A library or jar in the B project's `pom.xml`, can the project compile successfully from the command line via `mvn compile`? Please also open `File | Project Structure | Modules | your_current_module` and check if that library/jar is in `Dependencies` tab.

Comment: LJ, 'mvn compile' shows the same problem. The jar is in the dependencies tab.

Comment: You haven't added this jar/project B library correctly in this `pom.xml`. The IDEA uses the Maven configuration `pom.xml` as the single source of truth. Please recheck `pom.xml` and make sure that that library is added correctly there. Once you could use the `mvn compile` to build this project successfully, after reloading the Maven in IDEA, the IDEA should resolve it too.

Comment: are these projects a part of multi-module project? are they independent projects? could you please show pom.xml (without unnecessary details) for these projects?

Comment: @ursa pom.xml snippets added above. Separate projects at the same dir level. Again, proj-a is installed in local repo in the proper dir structure and the jar file contains the correct .class file, with the proper namespaces.

Comment: it is a maven issue, not IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There was a misconfigured plugin I overlooked. All good now. Thanks all for looking at this.